# Issues with entity mapping on JSON column - .net 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I've migrated to .net 7 and I wanted to use the new JSON column in entity but I'm struggling with the mapping (I guess it's the mapping).

My case is not in the basic documentation on Microsoft, I can't find an example and my solution is not working.

I have a class Action with some properties, which is working well.
I've added a new column Params in my table Action. This column should be a JSON column whose content is a different JSON depending on my use cases:

So let's say I have 2 classes, ActionChild1 and ActionChild2.

I have these children:

```
public class ChildAction1 : Action
{
    public ChildAction1Params Params { get; set; }
}

public class ChildAction1Params
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public DateTime DateDebut { get; init; }
    public DateTime DateFin { get; init; }
}

public class ChildAction2 : Action
{
    public ChildAction2Params Params { get; set; }
}

public class ChildAction2Params
{
    public List<Guid> ListIds { get; init; }
}
```

The goal is to map both of the children on my column Action.Params.

Here are my configuration files:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ChildAction2> entity)
{
    ActionConfiguration.ActionConfigure(entity);

    entity.Navigation(e => e.Params).IsRequired();
    entity.OwnsOne(e => e.Params, builder =>
    {
        builder.ToJson();
        builder.OwnsOne(b => b.ListIds, builder =>
        {
            builder.ToJson();
        });

    });
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ChildAction1> entity)
{
    ActionConfiguration.ActionConfigure(entity);

    entity.Navigation(e => e.Params).IsRequired();
    entity.OwnsOne(e => e.Params);
}
```

I had multiple issues:

- For ChildAction1 it can't find the property Params_Id.
- For ChildAction2 I had the error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Entity type 'ChildAction2Params' is
> an optional dependent using table sharing and containing other
> dependents without any required non shared property to identify
> whether the entity exists.  If all nullable properties contain a null
> value in database  then an object instance won't be created in the
> query causing nested dependent's values to be lost. Add a required
> property to create instances with null  values for other properties or
> mark the incoming navigation as required to always create an
> instance.'

Since I've added "builder.ToJson();" I have no more errors but I'm not sure if it's correct. (JFYI my database is SQL Server.)

Could you please help me map these two different objects correctly ?